# asp.net mvc publish not open in clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, iis-7, publish

I have two asp.net mvc projects on my server. (iis 7 and win server 2012R2).

Both (app1 port:80 & app2 port:83) work and open on server.
But app2 with port:83 open only on server and client can not open app2 with link http://IPserver:83

Edge => Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND

Chrome => ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Is there a config on IIS?

Comment: You say that app2 works - how do you know?  What steps do you take to verify it is working?  It would seem since the client cannot reach it that app2 is not working (completely).

Comment: app2 works works correctly on server. Home/Index opens (http://localhost:83). and api/user/getusers shows users correctly. but Home/Index does not open on client(http://serverip:83)

Comment: Based on what?  Edge connecting?  So your client listed above are coming from a different PC, elsewhere on the network?  But - the app1 _is_ working on separate PC?  These are the kinds of details you should update your questions with so people have the context to be able to understand the issue.

Comment: app1 open on server and other PCs. app2 open on server but not on other PSc. I test it on my smart phone too and not opened.

Comment: Anybody don't know?

Comment: I recommend updating your answer with that information and formatting it to be clear the steps you have already taken.  I would suspect this has to do with a firewall somewhere.  I recommend turning off app1 and reconfigure app2 to use the standard 80 port and then see if it is working.  If it works, that proves it is the non-standard 83 port being blocked somewhere.

Comment: I told to our server manager and he opened port 83 and resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, summarizing the solution:

1. Both `app1:80` and `app2:83` are working if connecting from the server itself (locally).
2. However, on a remote client, `app1:80` works, but `app2:83` does not work.

The recommendation was that there was likely a configuration issue with the network (or a firewall/port manager/port configuration on the server itself) that is blocking `port 83` since it is not a standard port like `port 80` is.

One way to test this is to shut down `app1`, reconfig `app2` to `port 80`, and see if the remote clients can connect to `app2` on `port 80`.

Comment: Right - I was summarizing the solution we figured out in the comments, so that anyone that finds this Q&A will be able to have a good summary of the actions, which will hopefully help them out.